# multiple link lists in shared memory in linux

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory

I am using C language and Linux as a platform.
I want to share number of structures in multiple processes, These structures have heads of Link Lists (These lists also should be shared )and pointers to each other. Memory required for  this data can go upto 1Mb.
As I cannot use Pointers in shared memory because they will be invalid for different processes.

There are two options:
1) either use offset values instead of pointers.
2) else, use different shared memories and use shared memory IDs (returned by shmget) instead of pointers.

As memory size to be shared is huge which option is better?
Can you suggest another option?

Thanks.

Comment: Are marshaling/unmarshaling operations something you could take into consideration?

Comment: You can arrange for the shared memory to be loaded at a specific address (the same address in all processes), so that as long as all pointers are to data in shared memory, they are equally valid in all processes.  The key point is ensuring that the shared memory segment is loaded at the same address in all processes.  If there's a common ancestor process and it loads the shared memory, all is sweetness and light; there are no further problems.  If the processes start without a common ancestor, then you have to agree on the address and make sure the system accommodates you.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler , How can I make sure that processes start with common ancestor process?

Comment: You know that they do if you have a master daemon that creates the shared memory and then forks worker processes.  If you need randomly started processes to connect to the shared memory, then you will need a mechanism to specify the address at which to attach shared memory, and you will specify that address when you use [`shmat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/shmat.html) or its analogues.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I used shmat() with specific address. Shared memory working is fine on my Linux Host machine. Linked list data and pointers are proper in all processes.

Comment: I used same code, compiled and loaded on target board. Address Pointers are same but linked list populated by one process is showing empty for another process. Is there anything that I should take care of?

Answer (score 3):

Use offset values.

Instead of pointers, use `size_t` offsets (in chars) from the start of the shared memory area.  You will need to do that everywhere where you access or manipulate these lists.

Edited to add:

Using the offsets this way compiles to very efficient code on most architectures, and you can use the [`__sync..()`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fsync-Builtins.html) built-ins to access and modify them atomically. Remember to use a built-in for *all* accesses, including reading: otherwise the value may have been atomically modified during a non-atomic read (or vice versa), leading to corrupted data.

If you know your shared memory will never grow above 4GB in size, then you can use `uint32_t` as the offset type instead, saving four bytes per "pointer" on 64-bit architectures. If you align all targets to a 32-bit boundary, then you can quadruple that to 8GB.

The extremely nice side effect from using `uint32_t` is that you can then manipulate *pointer pairs* (two consecutive offsets) atomically, on all 64-bit and some 32-bit architectures. Assuming you also have everything within the shared memory also aligned to 32-bit boundaries, and using offsets to each 32-bit unit, you can get/set pointer pairs atomically using

```
static inline void get_pair(void *const base, const uint32_t offset, uint32_t *const pair)
{
    uint64_t *const ptr = (uint64_t *)(offset + (uint32_t *)base);
    uint64_t        val;

    val = __sync_or_and_fetch(ptr, (uint64_t)0);

    memcpy(pair, &val, sizeof val);
}

static inline void switch_pair(void *const base, const uint32_t offset, const uint32_t *const new, uint32_t *const old)
{
    uint64_t *const ptr = (uint64_t *)(offset + (uint32_t *)base);
    uint64_t        oldval, newval;

    memcpy(newval, &new, sizeof newval);

    do {
        /* Note: this access does not need to be atomic, */
        memcpy(oldval, ptr, sizeof oldval);
        /* because the next one verifies it. */
    } while (!__sync_bool_compare_and_swap(ptr, oldval, newval));

    if (old)
        memcpy(old, &oldval, sizeof oldval);
}
```

The `__sync...()` built-ins work in GCC and Intel CC at least. The new C11 standard also adopts the C++11 -style [`__atomic..()`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html) built-ins, but it will take some time for the features to be implemented in current compilers.

If you write library code, or code you expect to be maintaining for several years, it will probably save you time to look up both built-in types, and add comments to yourself (or whoever is going to maintain it when it is time to transition between the built-ins), to describe which atomic built-in you'd use if they were already available.

Finally, do remember that using shared memory like this means you must observe the same caution as if you had multiple threads accessing the memory concurrently. Atomic operations will help, and there are some very clever tricks you can do with lists if you can manipulate pointer pairs atomically, but you still need to be very sharp about the corner cases and possible race conditions.

Comment: Thank you very much. This way of offset is helpful.